# Damaged Sd card. Sd card is damaged. Try reformatting

Tags: external-sd, stock-android, system-error

**While i am using my android phone i get this above  error .**

1.I have tried rebooting phone.

2.I also have tried to reformat in android but it shows same errors again and again my phone also not mounting sd card.

3.I have various ways like formating portions and chkdsk in command in pc.

*It is working fine in PC but not work in android so if you have any idea how to fix it. Any website or any YouTube video where i can learn how to fix it will really  help me........*

Answer (score 0):

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=FqR0BLUH_OI

Hope this is your answer. According to this video the error occurs when you have files on the SD-card that confuses Android OS. The video suggests you format the SD in FAT32 in a PC deleting the files. I suggest a full format (takes substantially more time to complete) as opposed to quick format.